# How to find the URL of my wordpress website in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, url

I installed WordPress on Ubuntu according to the website
https://www.journaldev.com/24954/install-wordpress-on-ubuntu, and I am now trying to find the URL of the website I created. I am not being able to do it though. I tried https://(my ubuntu server IP)/wordpress and it didn't work. I am a newbie in this field and would really appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What code exactly should I provide?